# Issue using if-else statement in spatial for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, spatial, r-sf

I'm working on a project that involves counting how many crimes of a certain type happen within 150 meters or 500 meters of a list of addresses. While I've been able to do this successfully without a for-loop, it's a bit cumbersome because of the different crime definitions I need to use, so I'm trying to shorten the process a bit.

There are three datasets, all sf objects. The first is `data_sf` an sf object with points, an ID variable, and `year`, a variable which specifies which crime dataset to use. The second two sf objects, `crime1516` and `crime1617` are crimes from 2015-2016 and then 2016-2017. My general approach is to use a for loop going through each row then

1. creating a bounding box for i row
2. a. if `year == 1`, calculate number of intersections with `crime1516` for i bbox
   b. else if `year == 1` calculate number of intersections with `crime1617`
3. count intersections and put it into i row of data.

However, I can't seem to get this year == 1 part to work.

Here is the code of the for loop I've tried to use:

```
data_sf$vc150m <- for (i in 1){
  bbox150m <- st_buffer(data_sf[i,]$geometry, dist = 150)
  if (data_sf[i, "year"] == "1"){
    vc150m <- st_intersection(x = bbox150m, y = crime1516_v)
    data_sf[i,]$vc150m <- vc150m %>% 
      group_by()
    count()
  } else if(data_sf[i,]$year == 2){
    vc150m <- st_intersection(x = bbox150m, y = crime1617_v)
    data_sf[i,]$vc150m <- vc150m %>% 
      group_by() %>%
      count()
  } else {
    data_sf[i,]$vc150m <- NULL
  }
}
```

Here is a function I've tried to integrate it into:

```
countcrimes <- function(d, output){
  output <- data.frame(data_sf$ID, data_sf$year, data_sf$geometry)
  for (i in 1:dim(data_sf)[1]){
    bbox150m <- st_buffer(data_sf[i,"geometry"], dist = d)
    if (data_sf[i,"year"] == "1"){
      vc150m <- st_intersection(x = bbox150m, y = crime1516_v)
      output[i,] <- vc150m %>% 
        group_by()
      count()
    } else if(data_sf[i,]$year == "2"){
      vc150m <- st_intersection(x = bbox150m, y = crime1617_v)
      output[i,] <- vc150m %>% 
        group_by() %>%
      count()
    }
  }
  return(output)
}

data_sf$vc150m <- countcrimes(150, vc150m)
```

Both of these return this error:

```
Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Based on the language, I'm guessing this is something to do with the `if` statement, but I can't figure out exactly what's causing it. I haven't found anything helpful around this issue, or really what it means. Any help with this, or anything else wrong with the for-loop/function, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data so we can reproduce your error?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance